# How to center the tabs in a navigation bar

Tags: css, navbar

How do i center the tabs in this navigation bar?
here is the html and css code for the nav bar i have made.

it is on JSfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/QPKe2/

```
<html> 
<body>
```

Please help..

Comment: Like [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/QPKe2/1/)?

Comment: @koala_dev you should post this as an answer, it is correct and deserves upvotes

Comment: edited the title from "tebs" to "tabs"

Answer (score 2):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPKe2/1/), here are the main changes:

```
#cssmenu ul{
    text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu li{
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left; remove this*/
}

#cssmenu li a{
    height:22px; /*add this here so all links have the same height*/
}
```